# Can someone help me with Android app for Search Movie

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an application to search for movies on Android and I don’t understand what is the mistake, can someone tell me what the problem is because I have already tried a lot

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val apiKey = "MY_KEY"
    private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.omdbapi.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val movieApiService: MovieApiService = retrofit.create(MovieApiService::class.java)

        val label = findViewById\<TextView\>(R.id.Label)
        val info = findViewById\<TextView\>(R.id.Info)
        val editText = findViewById\<EditText\>(R.id.EditText)
        val button = findViewById\<Button\>(R.id.Button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val text = editText.text.toString().trim()

            val call = movieApiService.searchMovie(apiKey, text)
            call.enqueue(object : Callback\<MovieResponse\> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call\<MovieResponse\>, response: Response\<MovieResponse\>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val movieResponse = response.body()
                        val movies = movieResponse?.search
                        if (!movies.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            val movie = movies\[0\] 
                            label.text = movie.title
                            val movieInfo = getString(R.string.movie_info, movie.releaseYear, movie.genre, movie.posterPath)
                            info.text = movieInfo
                        } else {
                            label.text = getString(R.string.movie_not_found)
                            info.text = ""
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call\<MovieResponse\>, t: Throwable) {
                    label.text = getString(R.string.error)
                    info.text = ""
                }
            })

            editText.text.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

I enter the name of the movie and press the button to send a request for the necessary information, but the application only writes me an error

Comment: And that error is…?

Comment: It looks like there are compile-time errors due to "\". Remove it from your code